# Cannot access class before initialization when imported from package, but works when imported from file path

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this class (`AppProvider.js`):

```js
import Provider from '../../node_modules/hydro/src/Provider.js'

export default class extends Provider {

    booting() {
        console.log('AppProvider booting')
    }

    booted() {
        console.log('AppProvider booted')
    }

}
```

which extends this class (`Provider.js`):

```js
export default class {

    booting() {
        console.log('Provider booting')
    }

    booting() {
        console.log('Provider booting')
    }

}
```

I am adding this class as a config value (`appConfig.js`):

```js
import AppProvider from '../providers/AppProvider.js'

export default {

    providers: [
        AppProvider,
    ],

    database: {
        host: 'prodhost',
    },

}
```

when i run the app, I get this when i `console.log` the config:

```
{
  providers: [ [class default extends default] ],
  database: { host: 'prodhost' }
}
```

in my package i have the following exports:

```js
export { default as App } from './src/App.js'
export { default as Provider } from './src/Provider.js'
```

i try and change the import to point to the exact same class, but using the package export rather than via the file path:

```js
import { Provider } from 'hydro'

export default class extends Provider {

    booting() {
        console.log('AppProvider booting')
    }

    booted() {
        console.log('AppProvider booted')
    }

}
```

and this gives me the following error:

```
export default class extends Provider {
                             ^
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Provider' before initialization
```

so changing this:

```js
import Provider from '../../node_modules/hydro/src/Provider.js'
```

to this:

```js
import { Provider } from 'hydro'
```

is causing an error for some reason?